# Android, Java - can asyncTask pass @struct modified class?

Tags: java, android, struct, android-asynctask

Hoping this may help the next person too.

in my Android app i need to pass several results from an AsyncTask.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask does not speak to types that "Can" be passed.

if java does have it's near equivalent to a struct in "C":
ie:

```
@Struct
class Member {
  string FirstName; 
  string LastName;  
   ....
  int BirthYear; 
}
```

**Can i pass it in an AsyncTask(Params, Progress, Result ) as Return?**
if so how?
I expect it may be formatting but not sure if this is even possible.

**TRIED**

```
   ...     asyncTask( String, void, Member );
   ...     asyncTask( String, void, class Member );
   ...     asyncTask( String, void, @Struct Member );
   ...     asyncTask( String, void, @Struct Member() );
```

Each throw a different error at compile

Comment: This is a little confusing, as you seem to be mixing several languages, here. If you're asking about Java, those three things an `AsyncTask` takes are called type parameters. They can be pretty much anything. In your case, provided you've defined the `Member` class correctly, the (partial) syntax would be `AsyncTask<String, Void, Member>`.

Answer (score 0):

Mike M.   had it right

I found another var named "Member"  and a slight rename and it compiles now